# Image is not deleting from database in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, pull

I am working on node.js express framework and mongoose and I am totally new to it.
    This is my schema.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ActivitySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    Activity:String,
    Photos:[{
        Photo:String,
    }]
});

module.exports =  mongoose.model('Activity', ActivitySchema);
```

This is my code.I am getting success on deleting but data is not deleted from database.

```
router.delete('/removeactivity/:_id/:_pid', function (req, res) {         
    Activities.findByIdAndUpdate(
        { _id: req.params._id }, 
        { $pull: { Photos: { _id:req.params._pid } } },
        function(err,user) {
            if(err) {
                res.status(500).json(err);
            }
            res.status(200).json(user)
        }
    );        
})
```

Comment: Does your photos array have _id field?

Comment: Yes It have object _ id by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `mongoose.Schema.ObjectId`, so your `_id` field is an `ObjectId`. In the `delete` logic you pick `req.params._id`, which is, I guess, a string and not `ObjectId`, so it won't work.

To create an `ObjectId` from a string, use `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` like this:

```
Activities.findByIdAndUpdate(
    { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params._id) },
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the new version of the document, after the update is applied, put `{new: true}` in the query. By default it is false.

```
Activities.findByIdAndUpdate(
        { _id: req.params._id }, 
        { $pull: { Photos: { _id:req.params._pid } } },
        {new : true},
        function(err,user) {
            if(err) {
                res.status(500).json(err);
            }
            res.status(200).json(user)
        }
    );        
})
```